How to write type hint for decorated implemented by a class
Here's a classical example of a decorator implemented by a class:
class Decorator:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.func(*args, **kwargs)

How to make __call__ have the same signature and type hints as func has?
I've tried the following code:
from typing import Callable, TypeVar, ParamSpec, Generic

PT = ParamSpec('PT')
RT = TypeVar('RT')


class Decorator(Generic[PT, RT]):
    def __init__(self, func: Callable[PT, RT]) -> None:
        self.func = func

    def __call__(self, *args: PT.args, **kwargs: PT.kwargs) -> RT:
        return self.func(*args, **kwargs)


@Decorator
def add(x: int, y: int) -> int:
    return x + y

But I failed to get the correct argument list of add in PyCharm.
Is it PyCharm's fault?


the basic example for ParamSpec should apply nicely here

@anthonysottile But ParamSpec cannot be put into Generic. By the way, the signature hasn't been copied yet.

"ParamSpec cannot be put into Generic": Who told you that?

@InSync I've updated the question. Such behaviour seems not to be properly detected by PyCharm. When I use a function decorator like def dec(func: Callable[PT, RT]) -> Callable[PT, RT}, PyCharm always shows the argument list. But this time, it only shows *args, **kwargs.

I think it's PyCharm. Pylance (which is backed by pyright) seems to handle this just fine on VSCode.

You want to explicitly replace the function with a callable with a specific signature, instead of replacing the function with an instance of a callable class that works the same but does not share the signature.
This shows the difference:
from typing import Callable, TypeVar, ParamSpec, Generic

PT = ParamSpec('PT')
RT = TypeVar('RT')


class Decorator(Generic[PT, RT]):
    def __init__(self, func: Callable[PT, RT]) -> None:
        self.func = func

    def __call__(self, *args: PT.args, **kwargs: PT.kwargs) -> RT:
        return self.func(*args, **kwargs)


def decorator(func: Callable[PT, RT]) -> Callable[PT, RT]:
    return Decorator(func)


@decorator
def add_func_decorated(x: int, y: int) -> int:
    return x + y


@Decorator
def add_class_decorated(x: int, y: int) -> int:
    return x + y


print(add_func_decorated(1, 2))
print(add_class_decorated(1, 2))

You will will find that both type hints and type checking work correctly for add_func_decorated, in PyCharm as well. While, for add_class_decorated type checking works, but the type hint displays as you showed in your question.

I guess this is a workaround for pycharm, but it shouldn't be necessary

IOW, the OP is replacing a function with a callable with a specific signature.

Yes, I think that's fair - reporting the behaviour to the JetBrains team as an error would be worth considering. I agree that the original source should have the same result - PyCharm's inference stops short of the correct conclusion. In the current version, I'd probably opt for the solution I suggested, unless maximum performance is a concern, in which case adding an annotation suppressing the warning could be considered. Having said that, I feel the fix with the function does help a human reader to better understand the resulting type as well, but that's opinion.


Is it PyCharm's fault?

Yes. Your code should have worked as-is, resulting in x: int, y: int being the signature displayed in the popup.
PyCharm's type checker is notoriously bad with ParamSpec and other slightly complex situations. Generally, the way to go is to turn off its rants and use a better type checker.
